# Elasticsearch match only and exactly given tags in tags array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

As an example, there are four documents

```
{id: 1, tags :["cat", "dog", "horse"]}
{id: 2, tags :["dog", "cat"]}
{id: 3, tags :["cat"]}
{id: 4, tags :["dog"]}
```

1. If I query tags with `["cat"]` I should only get `{id: 3, tags :["cat"]}`
2. If I query tags with `["dog"]` I should only get `{id: 4, tags :["dog"]}`

How can I construct such a query?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch scoring algorithm gives highest score to the document which has the exact search term, ie `cat` in your case and as you require only document which contains exactly `cat`, you can use `size` param with 1 value, this way your results will be much faster, as scripts are slow as they go through each and every documents during search time.

Adding a working sample.

**Index sample docs**

POST /index/_doc/1

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": [
        "cat",
        "dog",
        "horse"
    ]
}
```

doc 2

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "tags": [
        "dog",
        "cat"
    ]
}
```

doc 3

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "tags": [
        "cat"
    ]
}
```

doc 4

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "tags": [
        "dog"
    ]
}
```

And search query

```
{
    "size": 1, // Note
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tags": {
                            "value": "cat"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }    
}
```

return search result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "66069294",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.43250346,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "tags": [
                        "cat" // Note
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I think size returns only one document but there are more than one document containing only 'cat'

Comment: @ecka ohh, yeah than you can increase the size param and parse the response, and as results are sorted in desc order of score, as soon as you get a result which contains more than 1 item, you can ignore other results :) still it would be much faster than doing scripting at ES side

Comment: I think both answers seems like a workaround. What would be great is having an array and finding its equivalent in ElasticSearch. Having the exact match of an array would be great. It`s so easy to do in mongodb though. Both answers don't answers my question I will accept when if I find the solution

Comment: I did as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]:** Updated answer to work with both 5.x, and 7.x.

---

You can add a length filter for `tags` along with `term` query. See below for example using the data provided in question.

For versions newer than 5.x (tested on 7.x), this requires creating the mapping for index in a specific way (which is explained below).

1. Set `type` of `tags` to `keyword`

   ```
    PUT /my-index/_mapping
    {"properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"tags":{"type":"keyword"}}}
   ```
2. **OR** set `type` of `tags` to `text`, and enable `fieldata` for `tags`.

   ```
    PUT /my-index/_mapping
    {"properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"tags":{"type":"text","fielddata":true}}}
   ```

This strict mapping isn't required for 5.x.

After mapping, index the documents:

```
PUT /_bulk
{"create": {"_index": "my-index", "_id": 1}}
{"id": 1, "tags" :["cat", "dog", "horse"]}
{"create": {"_index": "my-index", "_id": 2}}
{"id": 2, "tags" :["cat", "dog"]}
{"create": {"_index": "my-index", "_id": 3}}
{"id": 3, "tags" :["cat"]}
{"create": {"_index": "my-index", "_id": 4}}
{"id": 4, "tags" :["dog"]}
```

Now search the indexed documents:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": {
              "value": "cat"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['tags'].length == 1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result should return the expected documents.

**Important Note**: Above steps will work for 5.x with one change: You need to provide document type (`_type`) in operations [because you can have more than one document types (and mappings) in one index in ES 5.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-create-index.html#mappings).

Comment: did you test this query, it returns `: "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [tags] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."` exception.

Comment: I had tested query on ES 5.x. You probably ran this query on 7.x.